# How to show external webpage on Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to show a static html webpage in a Sharepoint 2007 environment (webpage made with Gatsby if that would matter).

Is this possible?

Hosting the page somewhere else and loading it in an iframe is also an option. Is loading external pages by means of a webpart possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the Page Viewer web part to accomplish the same.

Let me know if that helps or you need further details

Comment: We solved it by external hosting, but thanks for the answer